# When was the time-frequency analysis invented?

Tags: signal-analysis

It seems there are several papers from the seventies but backtracking from the references gets quickly difficult. Who calculated for the first time a time-frequency representation of a signal?

Comment: The [Wigner Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_distribution_function) was already used in the 1930s in the context of quantum mechanics.

Comment: In modern form, perhaps circa 1800 by Gauss, Fourier and Lagrange (et.al.). But, according to wikipedia, the ancient Babylonians used it for astronomical calculations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis#History

Comment: @hotpaw2: Right, but isn't this about 'pure' Fourier analysis instead of a combined time-frequency analysis approach such as Wigner distribution and Gabor transform etc.?

Answer (score 4):

According to the preface of [Foundations of Time-Frequency Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=sjN2qq99-WwC&lpg=PR1&pg=PR1#v=onepage&q&f=false), a rough timeline is as follows:

- 1930 - Early development of quantum mechanics by H. Weyl, E.Wigner, and J. von Neumann.
- 1946 - Theoretical foundation of information theory and signal analysis by D. Gabor (cf. ["Theory of communication"](https://web.archive.org/web/20200806201955/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5298517)).
- 1980 - Time-frequency analysis established as an independent mathematical field (apart from engineering) by Guido Janssen.
- 1990 - Development of wavelet theory. Overview of the mutual influence given in ["The wavelet transform, time-frequency localization and signal analysis"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/57199) by Ingrid Daubechies.